# MS SQL Server stored procedure error 'incorrect syntax'

Tags: sql, asp-classic, ado

This is my stored procedure:

```
ALTER PROCEDURE its.sp_WriteTransaction

    (
    @LoginID int, 
    @PersonID int, 
    @BusinessID int, 
    @TransType smallint, 
    @LastHost varchar(15), 
    @TransData varchar(255)
)

AS

DECLARE @TransDate DATETIME
SET @TransDate = GETDATE()

INSERT INTO Transactions (LoginID, PersonID, BusinessID, TransDate, TransType, LastHost, TransData)
VALUES (@LoginID, @PersonID, @BusinessID, @TransDate, @TransType, @LastHost, @TransData) 
RETURN
```

This is my calling line:

```
    sql = "sp_WriteTransaction" & " " & Session("UserID") & "," & Session("PersonID") & "," & Session("bizID") & "," & TransType & "," & ClientIP & "," & TransData
```

But everytime I run it I get the following error message:

Error message:

Error Type:
Microsoft OLE DB Provider for SQL Server (0x80040E14)
Line 1: Incorrect syntax near '.0'.
/etearsheets/authorize/CheckAccess.asp, line 1163

What is wrong with the IP format that is causing the '.0' error and how do I correct it?

Thanks R.

Comment: **DON'T EVER EVER** use "sp_" as your stored parameter name prefix! Microsoft gets very angry if you do! It's a Microsoft-reserved prefix and you're just asking for trouble if you do use it! Use "proc_" or something else - or no prefix at all.

Comment: actually I don't have a choice, I am building these stored procedures according to company documentation and the 'sp_' issue is pertaining to SQL Server 7.0 Service pack 4, and we are on V.09.00.3042.  But thanks for the headsup I will bear it in mind.

Comment: This code is vulnerable to sql injection

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You aren't including quotations for your `varchar` columns.

Try this:

```
sql = "sp_WriteTransaction" & " " & Session("UserID") & "," & _
    Session("PersonID") & "," & Session("bizID") & "," & _
    TransType & ",'" & ClientIP & "','" & TransData & "'"
```

It's failing out on the IP address, since `127.0.0.1` is not a number. You're currently trying to pass it as float, which only uses one decimal. Encompassing it in single quotes forces SQL to parse it as a string.

Comment: While correct, I can't vote for this because it doesn't use query parameters and so is likely vulnerable to an injection attack.  Most of those values you might get away with it, but where does TransData come from?

Comment: @Joel: I didn't go into the SQL injection talk because this looked to be all system data, but you do raise a good point.

Comment: Ok you are right, the majority of data being used is system data.  Also, yes I am aware of the security flaws in the system and I have told the client so, but they seem to be a) unwilling to listen b) do not want to pay to get it sorted so I try and 'fit' things as I come across them but otherwise I am being paid to 'make it work' though I  do cringe sometimes just knowing what could happen.

Answer (score 1):

you need to put single quotes around the ClientIP value.

Answer (score 1):

Like the others said, you're not single quoting parameters.

Assuming...

```
Session("UserID") = 0000
Session("PersonID") = 4321
Session("bizID") = 1234
TransType = "GET"
ClientIP = "192.168.1.1"
TransData = "xyz"
```

then executing the following...

```
sql = "sp_WriteTransaction" & " " & Session("UserID") & "," & Session("PersonID") & "," & Session("bizID") & "," & TransType & "," & ClientIP & "," & TransData
response.write(sql)
```

would yield...

> sp_WriteTransaction
>   0,4321,1234,GET,192.168.1.1,xyz

What's more troubling is that you're passing unencoded strings to SQL because this leaves you vulnerable to SQL Injection attacks.  In this case it looks like the data might all be derived with no client origin but considering the nature/naivety of your question I suspect you are probably vulnerable elsewhere.

Here's an example of how you can protect your SQL

```
Session("UserID") = 11111
Session("PersonID") = 4321
Session("bizID") = 1234
TransType = "GET"
ClientIP = "192.168.1.1"
TransData = "xyz"

sql = "sp_WriteTransaction {0},{1},{2},{3},{4},{5}"
parameters = Array(Session("UserID"),Session("PersonID"),Session("bizID"),TransType,ClientIP,TransData)

Function BuildSQL(query, params)
    Dim result : result = query

    If Not IsArray(params) Then
        BuildSQL = Null
        Exit Function
    End If

    Dim i
    For i = lbound(params) to ubound(params)
        result = replace(result,"{" & i & "}",SQLEncode(params(i)))
    Next

    BuildSQL = result
End Function

Function SQLEncode (uVar)
    If IsNull(uVar) Then
      SQLEncode = "null"
    Else
      SQLEncode = "'" & replace(uVar,"'","''") & "'"
    End If
End Function

Response.Write BuildSQL("sp_WriteTransaction {0},{1},{2},{3},{4},{5}",parameters)
```

This code outputs the following...

> sp_WriteTransaction
>   '11111','4321','1234','GET','192.168.1.1','xyz'

You could take this a step further by putting SQLEncode and BuildSQL into their own file DataAccess.inc and making it available in all of your ASP files with an include statement.

e.g.

```
<!-- #include file="DataAccess.inc"-->
```

To do this you'll need to have Server Side Includes enabled in IIS and make sure the relative path in the #include statement is correct.

Comment: It would be safer and easier to use parameterised SQL rather than trying to encode the fields yourself.

Comment: @Luke : I am unaware that you can do parametrized SQL in Classic ASP.

Comment: @CptSkippy: You can do it. Take a look at http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms675101(VS.85).aspx